# What is this succulent?

Tags: identification, succulents

This succulent was purchased at a grocery store with out a tag. It is fairly quick growing, going from one inch to eight inches in a month and a half. Can anyone identify it?

[image: Unknown Succulent]
[image: Unknown Succulent]

[Note: There is a jade plant in the foreground of the first picture. The plant I am interested in is the single stemmed thing with grayish foliage. The plant has been grown in bright light inside the house.]

Comment: Looks quite intriguing - the leaves to the right in the first picture, near the bottom, are more boat shaped than cylindrical. Are they the same plant? And do you have it somewhere sunny - or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure it is [*Sedum pachyphyllum*](http://species.wikimedia.org/wiki/Sedum_pachyphyllum). If you water a lot, it grows very quickly and too much.

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite confident it's a kind of [Succulent plant](http://www.succulent-plant.com/thumbnails.html)  . Some guesses:

- Adromischus filicaulis ssp marlothii   [[pic]](http://www.plantegrassefrontignan.fr/plantes%20grasses%20mediterranennes/images/plantes%20grasses%20diverses/Adromischus%20filicaulis%20ssp%20marlothii.JPG)
- Adromischus halesowensis [[pic]](http://kaktusmert.tripod.com/sukkulent/Adromischus/Adromischus_halezowensis.jpg)
- Othonna capensis

Answer (score -1):

This looks more like "annual seablite" from Suaeda Genus.These grow on salty and Marshy areas and are well known for their rapid growth with little care.